# Ghidra: Reference to external symbols not resolved in decompile

Tags: ghidra, mips

In `main()` the references to **external** functions are not resolved in the decompile window, while they seem correct in the assembly:
[image]

- The other functions of the same application are fine, and the references to external and internal symbols are showed also in the decompile.
- The references to internal functions are showed correctly also in `main()`.

The application is for MIPS.

EDIT:
Context around the initialization of `local_518`:

```
                  //
                  // .text 
                  // SHT_PROGBITS  [0xde0 - 0x7f6f]
                  // ram:00010de0-ram:00017f6f
                  //
                  **************************************************************
                  *                          FUNCTION                          *
                  **************************************************************
                  int __stdcall main(int argc, undefined4 * argv)
                       assume gp = 0x32030
                       assume t9 = 0x10de0
     int               v0:4           <RETURN>
     int               a0:4           argc
     undefined4 *      a1:4           argv
     undefined4        Stack[-0x4]:4  local_4          XREF[2]:     00010df8(W),
[CUT...]
     undefined4        Stack[-0x518   local_518        XREF[181]:   00010df4(W),
                                                                    00010e40(R),
                                                                    00010e60(R),
                                                                    00010e7c(R),
                                                                    00010e98(R),
                                                                    00010eb4(R),
                                                                    00010ed0(R),
                                                                    00010eec(R),
                                                                    00010f08(R),
                                                                    00010f24(R),
                                                                    00010f40(R),
                                                                    00010f5c(R),
                                                                    00010f80(R),
                                                                    00010f90(R),
                                                                    00010fb0(R),
                                                                    00010fd4(R),
                                                                    00010fe8(R),
                                                                    00010ffc(R),
                                                                    00011044(R),
                                                                    0001109c(R)
[CUT...]
     undefined4        Stack[-0x5b0   local_5b0        XREF[10]:    00011018(W),
                                                                    00011168(W),
                                                                    0001139c(W),
                                                                    000115d4(W),
                                                                    000116ec(W),
                                                                    00011b94(W),
                                                                    00011bfc(W),
                                                                    00011fa0(W),
                                                                    00012360(W),
                                                                    000124a8(W)
                     _ftext       XREF[4]:     Entry Point(*), 
                     main                      __start:0001262c(*), 0002a048(*),
                                               _elfSectionHeaders::0000014c(*)
00010de0 02 00 1c 3c     lui        gp,0x2
     assume t9 = <UNKNOWN>
     assume gp = <UNKNOWN>
00010de4 50 12 9c 27     addiu      gp,gp,0x1250
00010de8 21 e0 99 03     addu       gp,gp,t9
00010dec 40 fa bd 27     addiu      sp,sp,-0x5c0
00010df0 02 00 82 28     slti       v0,argc,0x2
00010df4 a8 00 bc af     sw         gp=>_gp_1,local_518(sp)
00010df8 bc 05 bf af     sw         ra,local_4(sp)
00010dfc b8 05 be af     sw         s8,local_8(sp)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This probably happens because the decompiler can't infer the value of `local_518`. I'm not familiar with the kind of MIPS code generated here and I need the context where this value comes from, then it is probably possible to model this in a way that the decompiler understands.

Comment: Can you please share the sample you are looking at (for example by uploading it to malshare.com and referencing it by SHA256 hash here)?